# label control not displaying the text on production server. It works fine in development

Tags: label, production

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblWarehouse" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="lbl" Visible="true"></asp:Label>

    lblImagePath.Text = getWarehouse(strImgPath);

    private string getWarehouse(string ImgPath)
    {
        String strPath = "";
        String strfolderPath = "";
        int intFolderNo = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            intFolderNo = i + 1;

            // Begin Change by Triveni Gadipalli on 02/03/2014.

            //strfolderPath = @"\\\\\\\\CHC29\Warehouse" + intFolderNo.ToString() + "\\\\" + ImgPath+ "\\\\";

            String FolderNo = intFolderNo.ToString();
            if (intFolderNo < 10)
            {
                FolderNo = "0" + FolderNo;
            }

             strfolderPath = @"\\\\\\\\\\pnasxl40001.chcpa.loc\emrscans\wh" + FolderNo + "\\\\" + ImgPath + "\\\\";

            //    strfolderPath = @"\\\\\\\\pnasxl40001.chcpa.loc\emrscans\wh" + folderno + "\\\\" + ImgPath + "\\\\";
            //End Change  by Triveni Gadipalli on 02/03/2014.

             if (Directory.Exists(strfolderPath))
             {
                 strPath = strfolderPath;
                 i = 50;
             }

        }

        if (strPath == "")
        {
            return strfolderPath;
        }
        else
        {
            return strPath;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question isn't particularly clear, it would help if you expanded a bit more on where you think the problem might be?

Comment: This particular label is acting weird. If I say lblWareHouse.text = "test"; even that is also not getting displayed. Not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the line:

```
    lblImagePath.Text = getWarehouse(strImgPath);
```

reference lblWarehouse - that's the only label in your example code at least?

Comment: Thank you Steve, But I gave the wrong label text.Here is the correct one.  lblImagePath.Text = strImgPath;
            lblWarehouse.Text = strImgPath;//lblWarehouse(strImgPath);when both the lblImagePath and lblWareHouse text are same , even then the lblwarehouse is not displaying on the page when it is published to the server